# How can I create an alias for a function that executes another command?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

The command looks like this

```
vim -o `fzf`
```

I need to create an alias for this command. But when I source `~/.zshrc`, fzf command gets executed. The alias opens what I already opened using the fzf prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found this out. The solution is to create a zsh function and place it inside the `~/.zshrc` file.

```
function vo() {
  vim -o `fzf`
}
```